# JQuery insertAfter parent div

Tags: jquery

Below is my HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-12" id="docprop_00" class="docprop">                
        <div id="documentProperties" class="main_bg"></div>                 
</div>
```

JQuery

```
newElement.insertAfter("div.main_bg:last");
```

Here I am inserting the element after main_bg div, but I need to insert after the parent div of main_bg div. How can I do that??

Comment: What's wrong with: `newElement.insertAfter($("div.main_bg:last").parent());`???

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `.after()` method for that

```
$(".main_bg").parent().after(newELament);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this below code

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){
  $('.addnew').click(function(e){
  $('<p>New element</p>').insertAfter('.main_bg');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="docprop">
   <div class="main_bg">
     main_bg
   </div>
</div>

<button class="addnew">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the parent of the parent or you can use .after()

```js
$(".main_bg").parent().parent().append("<p>New element</p>");
```

```css
.col-xs-12{
  border:1px solid black;
  }
.main_bg{
  border:1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12" id="docprop_00" class="docprop">                Parent
        <div id="documentProperties" class="main_bg">Main Bg</div>                 
</div>
```